# Issue on creating PV volumes on GKE using access modes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, filebeat, persistent-volumes

I have a GKE cluster running on Google Cloud. I created a persistence volume and mounted my deployments, So the connectivity between my application and persistence are bounded successfully.

I also have filebeat running on the same cluster using the below link https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml

Both the application and filebeat also mounted successfully. The PV volume are created using **access modes: ReadWriteOnce** which is with GCE. But my cluster has many nodes running and my application is not mounted for all running pods. In google Cloud PV volumes are not supporting **access modes: ReadWriteMany**. So My filebeat too fails because of the application not mounted properly and filebeat has the capability of running in many nodes using deamonset. Is there a way to resolve the above issue.

Comment: I have posted an answer regarding FileBeat (it uses volumes different than apps). For what reason does your apps need volumes? Is that only for logging? hint: they should log to _stdout_.

Answer (score 1):

FileBeat should use volumes a bit different than volumes. Typically applications logs to *stdout* and then the *container runtime* (e.g. Docker daemon or containerd) persist the logs on the local node.

FileBeat need to run on every node, so it should be deployed using `DaemonSet` as you say. But it should also mount the volumes from the node using `hostPath` volumes.

See this part of the `DaemonSet` that you linked (no Persistent Volumes is used here):

```
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0640
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          # When filebeat runs as non-root user, this directory needs to be writable by group (g+w).
          path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement **access modes: ReadWriteMany** yes there are some option like you can use NFS or Gluster FS cluster.

if you just want do read option you can add the disk PD : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks **access mode** will be : **readonlymany**

You can use the File store : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes

Also you can use the cloud volume services : https://cloud.google.com/solutions/partners/netapp-cloud-volumes/overview (NFS & SMB)

If you just want **readonlymany** you can go with disk however if you want to perform write operation also you have to use NFS.

[Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/) example :

First create a Filestore instance.

```
gcloud filestore instances create nfs-server
    --project=[PROJECT_ID]
    --zone=us-central1-c
    --tier=STANDARD
    --file-share=name="vol1",capacity=1TB
    --network=name="default",reserved-ip-range="10.0.0.0/29"
```

Then create a persistent volume in GKE.

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
 name: fileserver
spec:
 capacity:
   storage: storage
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 nfs:
   path: /file-share
   server: ip-address
```

[IP_ADDRESS] will be available in the filestore console.

Now create persistent volume claim.

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: fileserver-claim
spec:
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 storageClassName: ""
 volumeName: fileserver
 resources:
   requests:
     storage: storage
```

Finally, mount the volume in your pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my-pod
spec:
 containers:
 - name: container-name
   image: image-name
   volumeMounts:
   - mountPath: mount-path
     name: mypvc
 volumes:
 - name: mypvc
   persistentVolumeClaim:
     claimName: claim-name
     readOnly: false
```

Document : https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares